# How to execute java program from eclipse windows to Linux server

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, intellij-idea, eclipse-plugin

My university server is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo), all the assignments should be executed on that server. while developing code is little difficult because there are no IDEs. Is there any way I can connect server from eclipse or IntelliJ, so that I can write code on my local machine and run on Univ server?
Usually, I connect to the server through winSCP, dump my code and execute it through putty.
PS: Only java is installed on the server.

Comment: It may be possible to map the folder on the server as a network drive in Windows.

Comment: What options do you have regarding ways to connect to the server?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there is a way since linux mainly deals with python, but there might be a third party extension available for eclipse that could help you do so.

However, in my experience with using eclipse you can only run it on your local machine